# Connection to (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB breaks on publish

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition to code in C#.

I have a Windows form app that uses a SQL Server local database. I am using SQL Server 2014 Express.

My current connect string is

```
connetionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = c:\\eq parser\\EQParser\\EQParser\\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";
```

This works fine when I run the program in the IDE, but once I publish the project and run the project application it can not connect to the local database.

The publish feature has been super downsized and only displays a few screens none of which allow me to customize my database connection string

[[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am under the assumption that the VS15 is creating a deployed version of the localDB automatically, but I am at a loss as to why publishing breaks my LocalDB Connection string?

Any ideas?

Comment: Does directory c:\\eq exist on your komputer?

Comment: If user which starts application is able to create db File when application is started?

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB is a developer-oriented version of SQL Server Express. That mean two things: first it's not designed or intended to be used on production systems, and second it needs to be installed - just like any other version of SQL Server Express - as a separate installation package before you can use your application

Comment: I thought that was the boon of sql server express. It allows you to deploy localdb. Thought I read that somewhere

Comment: I found the link where i read this.[link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)  LocalDB (SqlLocalDB.msi)

    LocalDB is a lightweight version of Express that has all its programmability features, yet runs in user mode and has a fast, zero-configuration installation and short list of pre-requisites. Use this if you need a simple way to create and work with databases from code. It can be bundled with Application and Database Development tools like Visual Studio and or embedded with an application that needs local databases.

Comment: P.K. I believe you are on the right track. The Publish project seems to create its own LocalDB not the one i am pointing to, Because the project is being built as a clickonce application, it installs differently for every user, hence harder to know where to point connection string too

Comment: I want to Bundle! anyone know how?